# Performance of for loop with an underscore iterator

Tags: python

Let's assume we have a list of something, namely, `ls`.
When we iterate over it using for loop, which one will yield better performance and why?
Please note that we don't need to refer actual elements of the list.

```
for _ in range(len(ls)): 
  # do something here

for _ in ls:
  # do something here
```

And, does the answer apply to list comprehensions also?

Comment: Intuitively the second one is faster, as in the first one there are two separate function calls, `len` and `range` respectively. `_` has nothing to do with this. Also, the second one is more pythonic. If you need the indices, `enumerate` should be preferred.

Comment: Looks like you're optimizing in the wrong place. The difference in speed between these two is unnoticeable.

Comment: The second way is generally considered more "pythonic" (and better).

Comment: first: `10 loops, best of 3: 195 ms per loop`, second: `10 loops, best of 3: 85.3 ms per loop`, with `1e7` elements in `ls`

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yeah, I know about optimizations in various fields, but in this case I just wanted to know the better way which does not sacrifice something. It is one definition of the optimum.

Comment: @Albo Thank you very much! Why aren't you write it as an answer? I wanna choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for _ in range(len(ls)): 
  pass  # -> 10 loops, best of 3: 195 ms per loop

for _ in ls:
  pass  # -> 10 loops, best of 3: 85.3 ms per loop

l = [0 for _ in ls] # -> 10 loops, best of 3: 309 ms per loop

l = [0 for _ in range(len(ls))] # -> 10 loops, best of 3: 422 ms per loop
```

Tested with `1e7`elements in `ls`.